# Can we have a user without a primary group?

Tags: users

Is it possible to have a user without a primary group in Linux? I found this question in one Linux test and wish to know about it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of groups:

1. Primary Group:

   This is the group applied to you when you log in; in most user cases it has the same name as your login name. The primary group is used by default when creating new files (or directories), modifying files, or executing commands.
2. Secondary Groups (AKA Supplementary Groups):

   These are groups you are a member of beyond your primary group. As an example, this means that if a directory or file belongs to the www-data group (as used by the web server process in this case), then all www-data group members can read or modify these files directly (assuming the permissions also allow for this).

When we create a user `foobar` using this command,

```
sudo adduser foobar
```

User `foobar` will be assigned the primary group, `foobar` (which is same as username), by default.

We can also change the primary group of the user as,

```
sudo usermod -g www-data foobar
```

The lowercase `-g` option refers to a primary group.

Now `foobar` has the `www-data` primary group context. We can change user's primary group but can't remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. While it's not possible to have a blank group in an entry in `/etc/passwd`, there is a group rather ironically called `nogroup`.

`nogroup` is the corresponding group associated with the user `nobody`. You can use it if your user doesn't need a "real", authoritative group. **Warning**: Apparently some systems run some processes as `nobody:nogroup`, as was [this user's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22520/what-is-nogroup-groups-purpose#comment30498_22521) case. If that's you, be careful who you give the group `nogroup` to.

See the Debian [Documentation about groups](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups):

```
nogroup (user: nobody): Daemons that need not own any files run as user nobody and group nogroup. Thus, no files on a system should be owned by this user or group.
```

Note that *no files should be owned by `nobody:nogroup`*.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. An entry in `/etc/passwd` with an empty group field is invalid. Every user account must have a user id and a primary group id.